# C# console Application with DB

Tags: database, sql-server, c#

i have c# program connected to SQL server and it is working very good but when i am trying to install this program in other PC it doesn't work unless SQL installed the data base is very simple .. i tried service-based database but it didn't help ether the connect String is :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + `applocation()` + @"\data\BackupMe.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

as `applocation()` function get my the current location of my app

so my Question how can i run my program in my clients PC without installing SQL server .. is it possible

Comment: SqlConnection is used to connect to a database server. If you want to run the database server on the same PC as the C# program, you need to install the server on that PC. You probably don't want to use the full SQL Server for this; there are better choices for databases intended to be embedded in an application.

Comment: is SQL server compact helps me in this situation ?

Comment: If you don't want to modify your application to use a different database server, SQL Compact is definitely better than full SQL Server. You can embed SQL Compact with your application, have your installer include it (check the license, but I believe it's free to redistribute). It uses the same APIs as full SQL Server, so it should work fine without any meaningful change to your application (might need to tweak the connect string, not sure).

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you are using [LocalDB](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/), a desktop SQLServer instance that runs on-demand, and only accepts connections from apps on the same box.

Second, your connection string points to LocalDB implicitly. if you want to refer to a remote database, the "Data Source" parameter must be changed to point to the server hosting the database.

So, First, select and install a SQLServer instance on a server or workstation that will act as a server. [SQLExpress 2014](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299) is free for non-commercial use.

Then add your database to the server. you will have to configure the server to [accept remote connections](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/).

Second, reconfigure your [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) to target the new server.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DatabaseServername;Initial Catalog=BackMeUp;Integrated Security=True"
```